# KeyCloak - how to access old User Account Console?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

How do you access or enable the old KeyCloak user account console? In this [blog post](https://www.keycloak.org/2020/09/new-account-console.adoc) about the new user account console, they say "The old account console is still available for those who need it", but I cannot find out where to enable that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to :

- Go to your Realm;
- And in Account Theme explicitly chose "keycloak"
- Click Save

In the Account dropdown menu you will see at least the follow:

- base;
- keycloak;
- keycloak.v2.

By default the new version is selected `keycloak.v2`. keycloak refers to the "old" version.